# PowerShell TFS list all files which have been added within a certain timeframe

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I use Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools. I know that to list all files that have been deleted in timeframe we can do something like this:

`Get-TfsItemHistory  "$/MyProject" -Version "D29/01/2010~D03/12/2019" -Recurse -IncludeItems '-Server tfs-server-name | Select-Object -Expand "Changes" | ' Where-Object { ($_.ChangeType -eq Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ChangeType::Delete ) } | 'Select-TfsItem | Select-Object Path | Sort-Object Path`

Now I want to list all files that have been added. Based on types listed in [ChangeType Enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changetype(v=vs.120).aspx) I tried to replace `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ChangeType::Delete` with `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ChangeType::Add` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to `-band` the ChangeType, as it's a flag enum and may contain multiple flags.

```
$ChangeType =  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ChangeType::Delete
(($_.ChangeType -band $ChangeType) -eq $ChangeType)
```

The process if further explained here at the post mentioned by Patrick:

- http://blog.hackedbrain.com/2009/04/01/getting-a-distinct-list-of-changed-files-from-tfs-using-powershell/